# Border-radius doesn't work with relative positioned image in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with following styling :

```
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

There is an image inside but the height is corresponding with the height of another div, containing text.

If the div contains not enough text, the image shifts up within the first div. Since it has overflow hidden, you will not see this. All of this went fine until I wanted to give a border radius to that first div, it just doesn't show up. This only happens in chrome, firefox and IE it does work.

Comment: Giving us the HTML that causes the problem might be usefull..

Comment: Even better: a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

This is a border-radius on an image inside a div, I'm not completely understanding what your question is, so modify this JSFiddle that I made to show me what it actually is.

http://jsfiddle.net/JGQwp/

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've updated the JSFiddle to show what's the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/JGQwp/3/

Comment: I've update the fiddle to have the border-radius on the image, is that what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/JGQwp/8/

Comment: Oh and the reason that there is no bottom border-radius because the overflow is hidden on the 150px height of the div...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what effect you want to achieve, but here is an example that works in Chrome (and others) by setting the image as the background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/dnsyn/1/

And one that applies the radius to the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnsyn/2/

Also, the `border-radius` property has been "un-prefixed" in all the browsers that support it, so you only need:

```
    border-radius: 20px;
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting the image as a background-image is not an option in this case..

Comment: @Boyye the second option might be better for you in that case.